# Can't display occupied voxels octomap using pointcloud2

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fairly new to this so let me know if there's a better way of doing things!

I'm attempting dynamic collision avoidance with a Kinect V1 and the ur5 moveit package on ROS kinetic. The PC is running Ubuntu 16.04 and i have the following packages installed:

- camera_pose
- octomap_mapping
- octomap_ros
- OpenNI
- openni_camera
- perception_pcl
- robotiq
- trac_ik
- universal_robot
- ur_modern_driver
- ur_scripts

I've been following the ROS tutorial on perception/configuration (link below) in an effort to have moveit process the point cloud into an octomap and display the occupied voxels: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_configuration/perception_configuration_tutorial.html

And am also aware of this other thread which is extremely similar, however i wasn't able to achieve a working result using just the information here: https://answers.ros.org/question/195770/moveit-collision-avoidance-with-point-cloud-2/

I have Openni working so can visualise the pointcloud2 okay in moveit and have completed all the steps in the above, including altering the sensor_manager.launch.yaml files. However when i echo the planning scene topic, `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene`, i am getting nothing. This is despite trying a number of static transform publishers to arrange everything with respect to `/world` (I would post images of my tf trees but i dont have enough karma).

**The moveit! config files used can be found at: (https://github.com/nis-ur/ur_kinect_meta/tree/master)**

**As requested, the terminal log when i launch ur5 planning:**

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch ur5_moveit_config ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true limited:=true
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/6ae42ada-891a-11e8-b1d3-62c9d7ce9d78/roslaunch-tegra-ubuntu-7323.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://tegra-ubuntu:38298/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /move_group/Manipulator/longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
 * /move_group/Manipulator/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/Manipulator/projection_evaluator: joints(shoulder_p...
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /move_group/controller_list: [{'action_ns': 'f...
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/max_range: 5.0
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_con...
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.025
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/balanced: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/heuristics: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/optimality: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BFMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BiEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/cost_threshold: 1e300
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_node_ratio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/init_temperature: 100
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/temp_change_factor: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BiTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::EST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/heuristics: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/radius_multiplier: 1.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::FMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/epsilon: 0.4
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LazyPRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LazyPR...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PDSTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PDST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/max_nearest_neighbors: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::ProjEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/delay_collision_checking: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SBL
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/max_failures: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARSkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SPARS
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/max_failures: 5000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwokConfigDefault/type: geometric::SPARStwo
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/degree: 16
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/estimated_dimension: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/max_degree: 18
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/max_pts_per_leaf: 6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/min_degree: 12
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.2
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::STRIDE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDEkConfigDefault/use_projected_distance: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountierNodeRatio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/init_temperature: 10e-6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/k_constant: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/max_states_failed: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/min_temperature: 10e-10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/temp_change_factor: 2.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::TRRT
 * /move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance: 0.01
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring: False
 * /move_group/use_controller_manager: False
 * /robot_description_kinematics/Manipulator/kinematics_solver: trac_ik_kinematic...
 * /robot_description_kinematics/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /robot_description_kinematics/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.02
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/max_velocity: 3.15
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/max_velocity: 3.15
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/max_velocity: 3.15
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
 * /robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13

NODES
  /
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[move_group-1]: started with pid [7340]
[ INFO] [1531764717.466433731, 2577.601000000]: Loading robot model 'ur5'...
[ INFO] [1531764717.466607399, 2577.601000000]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1531764717.654506310, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint shoulder_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.654610985, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint upper_arm_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.654696683, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint forearm_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.654748268, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint wrist_1_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.654796269, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint wrist_2_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.655033971, 2577.774000000]: IK Using joint wrist_3_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764717.655241527, 2577.774000000]: Looking in common namespaces for param name: Manipulator/position_only_ik
[ INFO] [1531764717.663599481, 2577.783000000]: Looking in common namespaces for param name: Manipulator/solve_type
[ INFO] [1531764717.677380792, 2577.793000000]: Using solve type Speed
[ INFO] [1531764717.792332030, 2577.904000000]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1531764717.815433269, 2577.926000000]: MoveGroup debug mode is OFF
Starting context monitors...
[ INFO] [1531764717.815535864, 2577.926000000]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1531764717.842420294, 2577.950000000]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1531764717.842503880, 2577.950000000]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1531764717.880690077, 2577.984000000]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/world '
[ INFO] [1531764717.900768782, 2578.004000000]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ INFO] [1531764717.949457813, 2578.046000000]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
[ INFO] [1531764718.070617004, 2578.159000000]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1531764718.225934172, 2578.305000000]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1531764718.233827635, 2578.312000000]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1531764718.236469264, 2578.312000000]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1531764718.240372426, 2578.314000000]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1531764718.245274780, 2578.321000000]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1531764718.247395917, 2578.323000000]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1531764718.250054283, 2578.324000000]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1531764718.250233007, 2578.324000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1531764718.250286256, 2578.324000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1531764718.250321329, 2578.324000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1531764718.250356626, 2578.324000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1531764718.250390835, 2578.324000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ INFO] [1531764718.573364143, 2578.643000000]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for 
[ INFO] [1531764718.573623829, 2578.643000000]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1531764718.645301682, 2578.708000000]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1531764719.089064576, 2579.103000000]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1531764719.089207267, 2579.103000000]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1531764719.089261380, 2579.103000000]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!
```

**And the terminal log when i launch rviz:**

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch ur5_moveit_config moveit_rviz.launch config:=true
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/6ae42ada-891a-11e8-b1d3-62c9d7ce9d78/roslaunch-tegra-ubuntu-7756.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://tegra-ubuntu:41009/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13
 * /rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725/Manipulator/kinematics_solver: trac_ik_kinematic...
 * /rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725/Manipulator/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.02

NODES
  /
    rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725 (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[rviz_tegra_ubuntu_7756_8226792173317731725-1]: started with pid [7773]
[ INFO] [1531764724.046184513]: rviz version 1.12.15
[ INFO] [1531764724.046849264]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1531764724.046903794]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1531764725.594316505, 2585.289000000]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1531764725.594873510, 2585.289000000]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
[ INFO] [1531764729.463324832, 2589.050000000]: Loading robot model 'ur5'...
[ INFO] [1531764729.463485604, 2589.050000000]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1531764729.869281539, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint shoulder_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869382341, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint upper_arm_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869433350, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint forearm_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869472199, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint wrist_1_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869521704, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint wrist_2_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869569513, 2589.348000000]: IK Using joint wrist_3_link -3.14159 3.14159
[ INFO] [1531764729.869630859, 2589.348000000]: Looking in common namespaces for param name: Manipulator/position_only_ik
[ INFO] [1531764729.903077463, 2589.363000000]: Looking in common namespaces for param name: Manipulator/solve_type
[ INFO] [1531764729.925311486, 2589.383000000]: Using solve type Speed
[ INFO] [1531764730.284061271, 2589.652000000]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1531764730.314902407, 2589.675000000]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1531764731.517646471, 2590.737000000]: No active joints or end effectors found for group ''. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ INFO] [1531764731.529964007, 2590.747000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'Manipulator' in namespace ''
[ INFO] [1531764732.625346157, 2591.687000000]: Ready to take commands for planning group Manipulator.
[ INFO] [1531764732.625532018, 2591.687000000]: Looking around: no
[ INFO] [1531764732.625612052, 2591.687000000]: Replanning: no
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295061/can%27t-display-occupied-voxels-octomap-using-pointcloud2/) by [nisur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35878/nisur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I finally managed to get this fixed, thanks a lot @Thadeu Brito and @aaditya_saraiya for your input. The problem turned out to be something to do with my tf static transform publisher.

Running the transform from the shell, i.e. something like...

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 world camera_frame 100
```

appeared to work fine when i checked `rosrun tf view_frames`. For some reason though, it didn't communicate properly with the octomap generator regardless of the transform parameters, frame parameters or the 'rate' parameter (100 in the above code). Echoing the `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` node proved that no info was being published.

As a last resort bit of trial and error I had a go at publishing the transform as part of the launch file, more like...

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 world camera_frame 100" />
</launch>
```

and this worked just fine. Not sure why this might be as both ways of doing it look identical? Anyway, this ticket is resolved. Thanks again,

Nick

---

Originally posted by [nisur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35878/nisur/) with karma: 28 on 2018-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0